# iRedAdmin SMTP sending error

Tags: debian, email, smtp

Recently i installed iredadmin on Debian. Then i tried to send mail using laravel framework with SMTP settings, but i cant get the email.

This is my mail error log:

```
    Nov 26 10:19:43 server postfix/smtpd[5029]: connect from server.example.eu[127.0.0.1]
    Nov 26 10:19:43 server postfix/smtpd[5029]: SSL_accept error from server.example.eu[127.0.0.1]: 0
    Nov 26 10:19:43 server postfix/smtpd[5029]: warning: TLS library problem: 5029:error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:s3_pkt.c:1261:SSL alert number 48:
    Nov 26 10:19:43 server postfix/smtpd[5029]: lost connection after STARTTLS from server.example.eu[127.0.0.1]
    Nov 26 10:19:43 server postfix/smtpd[5029]: disconnect from server.example.eu[127.0.0.1]
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your logs are saying it all. Change the connection type from TLS only to STARTLS. Hope this will help.

Comment: Same problem...

Comment: My main.cf postfix file: http://pastebin.com/gspj8BeA

Comment: can you tell me the version of TLS and STARTLS you were using ?